# $X'$ is separable then $X$ is reflexive (Wrong argument)

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I showed that $X'$ is separable then $X$ is reflexive. But it's false, because  $(c_{0})' = l_{1}$ is separable and  $(c_{0})''=(l_{1})' = l_{\infty}$ (so $c_{0}$ isn't reflexive). So I use some wrong argument in some place, I'd like to know where I'm missing.

Let $X$ Banach space where $X'$ is separable. Let $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ a bounded sequence in $X$. There exists a $k >0$ such that $\|x_{n}\| < k$, so $y_{n}= \frac{x_{n}}{k} \in B_{X}$ where $B_{E}=\{x \in E | \|x\| \leq 1\}$ for $E$ a normed space.

Consider $J: X \to X''$ given by $J(x)(f)=f(x)$.  So, $(J(y_{n}))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a bounded sequence in $B_{X''}$.

By Banach-Alaoglu's Theorem, we have that $B_{X''}$ is compact in $\sigma(X'',X')$.

We have that $E$ is separable then $B_{E'}$ is metrizable in $\sigma(E',E)$. If $X'$ is separable, we have that $B_{X''}$ is metrizable in $\sigma(X'',X')$. So, $B_{X''}$ is a compact metric space.

So there exists a convergent subsequence of $(J(y_{n}))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $\sigma (X'',X')$, without loss generality, $J(y_{n}) \to_{w^{*}} T$ with $T \in B_{X''}$ in $\sigma (X'',X')$.

Define $A:= \{ y_{n} | n \in \mathbb{N} \} \subseteq  B_{X}$. Note that  $\overline{A}^{\sigma (X,X')}  \subseteq  \overline{B_{X} }^{\sigma (X,X')}$

$J(\overline{A}^{\sigma (X,X')}) = \overline{J(A)}^{\sigma (X'',X')}$  recall that $J: (X, \sigma (X, X')) \to (J(X), \sigma(X'',X'))$ is a homeomorphism.

$\overline{J(A)}^{\sigma (X'',X')} \subseteq J (\overline{B_{X} }^{\sigma (X,X')}) = \overline{J(B_{X})}^{\sigma (X'',X')}$

We have that $J(\overline{A}^{\sigma (X,X')}) = \overline{J(A)}^{\sigma (X'',X')}  \subseteq \overline{J(B_{X})}^{\sigma (X'',X')} = B_{X''}$ by Goldstine's Theorem.

We obtain that  $J(\overline{A}^{\sigma (X,X')}) = \overline{J(A)}^{\sigma (X'',X')}$ is closed in $\sigma(X'',X')$  and  $J(\overline{A}^{\sigma (X,X')}) \subseteq B_{X''}$.

There exists $y \in \overline{A}^{\sigma (X,X')}$  such that $J(y) = T$,  so $J(y_{n}) \to_{w^{*}} J(y)$ in $\sigma(X'',X')$. Using that $J: (X, \sigma (X, X')) \to (J(X), \sigma(X'',X'))$ is a  homeomorphism, we have that $y_{n} \to_{w} y$ in $\sigma(X,X')$.

We showed that every bounded sequence in $X$
has a subsequence which converges weakly to an element of $X$. By Eberlein-Smulian's theorem, we that $B_{X}$ is compact in $\sigma(X,X')$. Then $X$ is a reflexive by Kakutani's Theorem.

We showed that $X'$ is separable then $X$ is reflexive. But it's false, because  $(c_{0})' = l_{1}$ is separable and  $(c_{0})''=(l_{1})' = l_{\infty}$ (so $c_{0}$ isn't reflexive).

**Remark (after the answer of @yaqa)**

We have that:

If X' is separable. Then

$X$ is reflexive if, only if,  $J(X)$ is closed in $\sigma(X'',X')$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$J\left(\overline{A}^{w}\right) = \overline{J(A)}^{w^*} \cap J(B_X)$

Comment: And in fact with $A = B_X$ it is easily seen that the original claim was not correct.